# can't open url in browser

Tags: android

I'm trying to open a url in a web browser using the following code,

**does not work**

```
Bundle ex=in.getExtras();
link=ex.getString("link");
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent t=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri u=Uri.parse(link);
    t.setData(u);
    startActivity(t);   
}
```

but i'm havinng a weird problem.When i use the exact url instead of string "link" everything works as it should, but when i go with the String link that i created i get the "no activity found to handle intent" exception.But i'm sure the link contains the right url, the same that i used before.

**this works**

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent t=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri u=Uri.parse("http://google.com");
    t.setData(u);
    startActivity(t);   
}
```

i'm sure that in the first case link contains the url (http://google.com), besides i printed on a textview to check!

Comment: Can you post both examples?

Comment: Can you post how you declare and initialize the paramter "link"? What does it say when you print out "link" to logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was caused by a whitespace at the of 'link'.I used link.trim() and it worked correctly. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` acts differently depending on the data you pass with `setData`.
So if you pass an Uri/URL it will open the browser, but if you pass a String (it doesn't matter that the string actually contains an url) it doesn't know what to do with it.

If you need to create the link from code you can use [Uri.withAppendedPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#withAppendedPath%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: but even in the first case i'm passing with setData a uri, not a string

Comment: yep.And so that i'll make it even worse i'm showing the link that is contained in 'link' to a textview and it's displayed correctly, and also when i click it, it correctly opens it to the browser.But it doesn't work at the button where i'm using the code i posted with the same always 'link'!!!

Comment: Well, the problem was caused by a whitespace at the of 'link'.I used link.trim() and it worked correctly.
Thank you guys for your help.